# IMPORTRANGE to import multiple Google Sheets into one vertical column?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am having a bit of an issue using IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets to import multiple sheets into a single column on a master sheet and whenever one of the sheets is updated, it automatically creates the new row on the master. Would there be a better way to do it other than IMPORTRANGE?

Answer (score 4):

You can attach arrays onto each other by using embedded arrays. See more: [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

This is a basic array `={1,2,3,4}` and has an output that looks like this:[image]

To append an array on-top of another array you would use a semicolon `;`; instead of a comma `,`. Like so: `={1;2;3;4}` which will look like this:

[image]

To append multiple arrays together you would take one array `{1;2;3;4}` and append it to another like: `{1;2;3;4};{5;6;7;8}` and encase both with the embedded array syntax like so:

```
{{1;2;3;4};{5;6;7;8}}
```

**However**, one strict limitation is that both arrays need to be the same width, so if you have `{{1,2};{1,2};{1,2,3}}` you will receive an error becuase not all the array elements have the same number of columns.

**How to import multiple ranges on top of each other?**

Using the above concepts, assuming both `IMPORTRANGE()`'s are the same width:

```
={IMPORTRANGE(sheet, range);IMPORTRANGE(sheet, range)}
```

Will import two ranges one on top of the other.

Comment: did not pull the second importrange.

Comment: Using more than one importrange in a single formula will cause issues due to the lack of permission to link other sheets.
I found that Google Sheets ask for permission the very first time using only one importrange in formula.
So my suggestion is to change the formula to include only one importrange at a time and give permission to access the linked Sheet.
Once the access to every needed external sheet is given you can use multiple importrange in the same formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) (that does not require authorisation). For example for a single row (Row2) from each of three sheets (`1`, `2` and `3`), with the headers from '1'!A1:C1 :

```
=query({'1'!A1:C2;'2'!A2:C2;'3'!A2:C2})
```

The `;` is for vertical stacking where the locale's general separator is `,`.