# Concatenate two Google spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have two Google spreadsheets I want to concatenate to make a third.
I get the lines of one spreadsheet with this formula:

```
=QUERY(ImportRange("1IBOBd5LPuN4f2oLnHAVasmAiCgjjtC_WC8uH79RC7wq"; "Suivi cours!A1:K521"); 
 "Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col11 Where month(Col9) = 1"; 0)
```

This works well. But I have to get the lines from another spreadsheet the same way. And I don't know what should I do to get the lines of the first Sheet followed by the lines of the second Sheet.  How do I place these sequentially into a new spreadsheet?

Example:

**Sheet 1**:

```
Line 1 Sheet 1
Line 2 Sheet 1
Line 3 Sheet 1
```

**Sheet 2**:

```
Line 1 Sheet 2
Line 2 Sheet 2
```

Then:
**I need to get in Sheet 3**:

```
Line 1 Sheet 1
Line 2 Sheet 1
Line 3 Sheet 1
Line 1 Sheet 2
Line 2 Sheet 2
```

Comment: Improved formatting; clarified question wording.

Answer (score 1):

Following the same concept as my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36852051/3547347

You can use embedded arrays to solve this problem.

**Assuming you want to combine your `IMPORTRANGES`:**

Combine your import ranges like so:

```
{{IMPORTRANGE("mySheet", "myRange")};{IMPORTRANGE("mySheet", "myRange")}}
```

And stick them back into your query function:

```
QUERY({{IMPORTRANGE("mySheet", "myRange")};{IMPORTRANGE("mySheet", "myRange")}} ; 
"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col11 Where month(Col9) = 1 " ; 0)
```

**If you instead want to combine two ranges from two worksheets:**

Same concept as above, but replace the `IMPORTRANGE()` with your sheet references, ie:

```
{{Sheet1!A:C1000};{Sheet2!A:C500}}
```

**Note:** Both ranges must have the same width. You cannot use embedded arrays on ranges with varying widths.

Comment: @KarlReyka Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted